# MultiClass Classification Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, multiclass-classification

Im building a CNN Classification model to with classes = [Pneumonia, Healthy, TB], i already made some code to build the model and it went pretty well. But the problem is the confusion matrix is a little bit weird for me. I got a pretty well result for the accuracy of the testing_data with the accuracy of around 85%. i use this code for making the confusion matrix :

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def confussion_matrix(test_true, test_pred, test_class):
    cm = confusion_matrix(test_true, test_pred)
    disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=test_class)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
    disp.plot(ax=ax,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
    plt.show()
```

```
testing_pred_raw = model.predict(testing_generator)
testing_pred = np.argmax(testing_pred_raw, axis=1)
testing_true = testing_generator.classes
testing_class = ['Pneumonia', 'Sehat', 'TB']
confussion_matrix(testing_true, testing_pred, testing_class)
```

Note : Sehat = Healthy

i already got the confusion matrix but the spread is pretty weird (is like is not even 85% accuracy). Heres the result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRiAj.png)

Is this result is correct (maybe because i read the confusion matrix incorrectly) or theres something in my code that can be modify?

I already tried the thing as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its seems the problem is not on the data or the CNN Model. my problem can be fix by just set the shuffle on my test and validation generator to False.

```
def data_generators(TRAINING_DIR, VALIDATION_DIR, TESTING_DIR):

  training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                        horizontal_flip = True)

  training_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DIR,
                                                    batch_size = 32,
                                                    class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                    target_size = (128, 128))
  
  validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                          horizontal_flip = True)
  
  validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(VALIDATION_DIR,
                                                    batch_size = 32,
                                                    class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                    shuffle = False,
                                                    target_size = (128, 128))
  
  testing_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
    
  testing_generator = testing_datagen.flow_from_directory(TESTING_DIR,
                                                    batch_size = 32,
                                                    class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                    shuffle = False,
                                                    target_size = (128,128))

  return training_generator, validation_generator, testing_generator
```

But i dont know why if i set the shuffle = True in validation data, the prediction is still good. But the important part is setting the Shuffle = False in the testing data.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your confusion matrix shows accuracy of about 32%

[image]

There are 15 correct classifications and 15+32 = 47 classifications in total.
15/47 is ~32%.

#### I can't explain where you got your accuracy of 85% from

It is not from this dataset. Is there any chance that your model was scoring 85% on the training set, and this performance of 32% is on a test set?

#### Ah, thank you for the additional info

> oh yeah.. i split the data for train, validation, and testing data.
> The ratio is 0.7,0.2,0.1. so the train has 314 image, validation has
> 89 image, and testing has 47 image. so for the testing only use the 47
> image.

So now we know that the accuracy is ~85% on the training set, ~81% on the validation set, and ~32% on the test set.

That is why we have a test set: to make sure we haven't deluded ourselves!

If you want to check whether this interpretation is correct, feed in the training data, or the validation data, into the confusion matrix plot. You should see much more agreement along the main diagonal.

Comment: I already train the model using model.fit with train and valid data with this line of code : history = model.fit(training_generator, epochs=100, validation_data=validation_generator, verbose=1, callbacks=[callbacks]) this got the val and accuracy below : coss: 0.4896 - accuracy: 0.8599 - val_loss: 0.6847 - val_accuracy: 0.7416 then i test with the testing data using this code : results = model.evaluate(testing_generator, batch_size=32) and then the result is around 81% this time : loss: 0.5798 - accuracy: 0.8125 

like this

Comment: Ah! The 85% was the accuracy on the TRAINING set. On the training set, accuracy always ends up high, if you have a big enough network. The big question is performance in the unseen data, and that is always worse.

Comment: so how about the 81% that i evaluate using the model.evaluate function. the result is 81%. is it because my data is so small? i have around 450 picture for this cnn model

Comment: Hmmmm.... If you have so many cases, why is the confusion matrix only 47 cases? Check the size of the `test_true` and `test_pred`.

Comment: oh yeah.. i split the data for train, validation, and testing data. The ratio is 0.7,0.2,0.1. so the train has 314 image, validation has 89 image, and testing has 47 image. so for the testing only use the 47 image.